# Android Volley: Bad URL in ImageRequest

Tags: android

I'm on Android Studio 4.1.3 (last release). I'm using the Android Volley library and I'm trying to retrieve an image from and API via ImageRequest. The URL that I'm using is the following one:

```
private String skinUrl = "http://crafatar.com/renders/body/680f95cff25d4f178fea90e2c003bebf.png?size=512&overlay&scale=7"
```

While using this url in the method

```
private void requestImage() {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(skinUrl, response -> skin.setImageBitmap(response),
                0,
                0,
                ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP,
                null,
                error -> {
        });
        requestQueue.add(imageRequest);
    }
```

I get this error message

```
NetworkDispatcher.processRequest: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL 
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException(NetworkUtility.java:164)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:145)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:132)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
     Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:601)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:498)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:447)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:82)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:104)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:132) 
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111) 
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
```

I've also tried to use the method URLEncoder

```
skinUrl = URLEncoder.encode(skinUrl);
```

but the result is the same.
The problem is only appening with the ImageRequest, because I'm also retriving json data from another API.

Comment: What if you remove the query parameters and just do: `http://crafatar.com/renders/body/680f95cff25d4f178fea90e2c003bebf.png` ?

Comment: what if you use https instead of http . for me i tested and it's work ( Im not Tested with http)

Comment: I've tried already with https and also without parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple bro use glide image loading library

because its top of android and fast and efficient for image loading just you have to put your image URL and image is load but you have to apply internet permission in manifest.

visit doc - https://github.com/bumptech/glide